# Is Statefull Service any good

Tags: java, web-services

Stateless services means there is no memory of the past. Every transaction is performed as if it were being done for the very first time.

Stateful services means that there is memory of the past. Previous transactions are remembered and may affect the current transaction.

It seems stateless always win. Is there any advantage of using stateful nowdays ?

Comment: it totally depend on your use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its apparent no system is ever 100% stateless. There is always some sort of state memory however how minimal. Now the real deal should be how much state data you need to optimize your system.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-introduction